# "Why has this watch stopped?" Thought Ahmed,

Tags: american-english, word-usage, british-english

"Why has this watch stopped? " Thought Ahmed, 
How to change this sentence into Narration? 
I tried to make its Indirect speech, but I could not change it.

Comment: Ahmed wondered why the/this watch has stopped.

Comment: No, ...HAD stopped.

Answer (score -1):

Ahmed astonished why the watch had stopped.

Ahmed astounded why the watch had stopped.

Ahmed engrossed why the watch had stopped.

Ahmed fascinated why the watch had stopped.

Ahmed gaped why the watch had stopped.

Ahmed bewildered why the watch had stopped.

Comment: Those are all ungrammatical.

Comment: They are similar words for wonder.

Comment: No. They are adjectives, while _wonder_ is a verb. Except _gaped_, which is intransitive and cannot take an object.

Comment: I am surprised at her conduct. I am astonished at her conduct. If we are changing like this.  Why can't we use similar words.?

Comment: Those are fine. The ones in your answer have no verb, which is ungrammatical.

Comment: Google it please. These are verbs, I found them from Google,

Comment: Tell me which one?

Comment: They are not stative verbs. Try a dictionary, rather than Google. “She was astounded” = grammatical. “She astounded him” = grammatical. “She astounded” = ungrammatical. Any native speaker will tell you this.

Comment: Well,  I would check them.

Comment: A little pointer: Learning about 'transitive' and 'intransitive' verbs will be of some help. That will explain why a verb such as 'astound' cannot stand alone without a 'direct object'.